# Illegal assignment from void to Id, even after the sObject has been inserted?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am writing unit tests for some code that I wrote last month.

Given this code:

```
    private static void generateTestData() {
        HeddySummaryForProfileImport__c testSummary = new HeddySummaryForProfileImport__c();
        testSummary.Name = 'testSummary name'; 
        testSummary.ProfileId__c = '999999'; 
        testSummary.ProfileType__c = 'company'; 
        testSummary.Body__c = 'testSummary body'; 
        testSummary.Title__c = 'testSummary title'; 
        insert testSummary;
        Id testSummaryId = testSummary.Id;

        return testSummaryId; 
   }
```

I get this error:

> Illegal assignment from void to Id

I assume this about this line:

```
    Id testSummaryId = testSummary.Id;
```

but this comes right after an "insert". I thought the "insert" set the Id for the object?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the problem was with the "void" in the function signature, held over from an earlier version. I changed this to Id.

Comment: Odd that it would even compile

Comment: I agree. I actually had several strange cases where I used the Force CLI and ran "force import" and got a bunch of error messages, then fixed all the error messages, and so I thought the code was compiled and working. Yet when I ran the tests, I got additional errors such as this. I wonder if Force CLI runs all the checks that I assume? Perhaps not?